# django select_related().values() not returning all fields from 2 tables

Tags: python, django

I have 2 tables, one child (Car) and the other parent (Dealership). I'm using the orm query `Car.objects.all().select_related('dealership').values()` to perform a left join which would give me all the fields from both cars and their related dealerships but that's not happening as I'm only able to get all the fields from the Car model.

```
class Dealership(models.Model):
    ...

class Car(models.Model):
    dealership = models.ForeignKey(Dealership, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    ...
```

I read it in a different question that with .values() I'll have to explicitly mention all the required fields but there are just too many fields to enter manually. Is there a cleaner solution to this?

Comment: Please don't use `values()` (https://django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html), it also makes not much sense to think in terms of database queries, you should write the queries in terms of *models* and *relations*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Got your point but I need to ultimately return the response as JSON for which I need to use .values()

Comment: no, normally to do this you can use [Django's *serialization framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/), or for APIs, it is usually better to work with the [serializers fo the Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). These are made especially to prevent using `.values()`, since `.values()` are a "flat" dictionary, not an object with references to other objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Tried using ```serializers.serialize('json',  Car.objects.all().select_related('dealership'))``` but still not able to fetch any fields from the Dealership model.

Comment: no, for items with relations, likely the Django REST framework, or [TastyPy](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) should be used.

Answer (score 2):

`select_related` is a performance booster and doesn't return you anything more than `Car.objects.all()` . read about it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

You should get dealerships from selected record. for example:

```
car = Car.objects.select_related('dealership').get(id=1)
dealers = car.dealership
```

If you are going to return a json from these info, i recommend you to user drf and serializer to handle this

Comment: There is no "selected record". I'm trying to fetch all Cars and their related Dealerships.